# How to efficiently check a JSON array for values in T-SQL

Tags: json, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I want to find multiple rows where a JSON array contains a specific value or values. Sometimes all match items will need to match (`AND`s), sometimes only some (`OR`s) and sometimes a combination of both (`AND`s and `OR`s).

This is in Microsoft SQL Server 2017.

I've tried doing an `AS` statement in the select but that resulted in the alias created for the subquery not being recognised later on in the subquery.

The bellow example **works**, it just seems innificent and has code duplication.

How would I only specify `SELECT VALUE FROM OPENJSON(JsonData, '$.categories'` once? Or  perhaps there is some other way to do this?

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE
(
  Id int, 
  JsonData nvarchar(4000)
);

INSERT INTO @TestTable
    VALUES 
    (1,'{"categories":["one","two"]}'),
    (2,'{"categories":["one"]}'),
    (3,'{"categories":["two"]}'),
    (4,'{"categories":["one","two","three"]}');

SELECT [Id]
  FROM @TestTable
  WHERE ISJSON(JsonData) = 1
  -- These two lines are the offending parts of code
  AND 'one' in (SELECT VALUE FROM OPENJSON(JsonData, '$.categories'))
  AND 'two' in (SELECT VALUE FROM OPENJSON(JsonData, '$.categories'));
```

The table format cannot change, though I can add computed columns - if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if this helps you...

It might help to transform the nested array to a derived table to use it as a CTE. Check this out:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE
(
  Id int, 
  JsonData nvarchar(4000)
);

INSERT INTO @TestTable
    VALUES 
    (1,'{"categories":["one","two"]}'),
    (2,'{"categories":["one"]}'),
    (3,'{"categories":["two"]}'),
    (4,'{"categories":["one","two","three"]}');
```

--This is the query

```
WITH JsonAsTable AS
(
    SELECT Id 
          ,JsonData
          ,cat.*
    FROM @TestTable tt
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(tt.JsonData,'$.categories') cat
)
SELECT *
FROM JsonAsTable
```

The approach is very close to the query you formed yourself. The result is a table with one line per array entry. The forme `Id` is a repeated grouping key, the `key` is the ordinal position within the array, while the `value` is one of the words you are searching for.

In your query you can use `JsonAsTable` like you'd use any other table in this place.

But - instead of the repeated `FROM OPENJSON` queries - you will need repeated `EXISTS()` predicates...

A hacky solution might be this:

```
SELECT Id
      ,JsonData
      ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JsonData,'{"categories":[','",'),']}',',"'),'","',',')
FROM @TestTable
```

This will return all nested array values in one string, separated by a comma. You can query this using a `LIKE` pattern... You could return this as computed column though...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @shnugo! Good approach - I didn't know you could do that :) Unfortunately the JSON data I am dealing with is unstructured and changes wildly per row. So I can't really do anything like that.

Comment: @Locdarb, well, that's the problem with generic data containern... You never really know what's inside ;-) I might be able to help you if you'd set up a [mcve]. Some more (wildly changing) samples and the expected result...